# Convert time format string with moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am getting a date string in format '2020-01-22T19:52:13.180Z' from an API. I am using momentjs library for datetime manipulation. But I am not able to find a format in momentjs to convert the above string into valid javascript date or moment object. [I have no control over the response returned from the API].

Comment: *"The above format is used by sql server by default for storing DateTime."* No it isn't, SQL Server doesn't store dates (and times) in a format at all, it stores them as a binary value. It's the presentation (and sometimes interpretation if you decide to store a date and time value as a string in code) layer than chooses the format; SQL Server doesn't do anything about it. Hence why i've asked what this has to do with SQL Server, as nothing in yoru question is related to it, apart from that the API is getting data from SQL Server (which isn't relevant to the question being asked).

Comment: `new Date('2020-01-22T19:52:13.180Z')` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Larnu My mistake. Changed the question title. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note, as well, the `T` means Time, not Timezone. `Z` is related to the Timezone and effectively means UTC (or +00:00).

Answer (score 1):

You can get javascript date object by using the Date constructor itself.
`new Date("2020-01-22T19:52:13.180Z")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can format Date manually as you want. Refer to the following code.

```
let current_datetime = new Date("2020-01-22T19:52:13.180Z")
let formatted_date = current_datetime.getDate() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getFullYear()
console.log(formatted_date)
```